# Failed to install Qiskit through Anaconda

Tags: pip, anaconda, anaconda3, qiskit, pep517

Windows 10

Anaconda Python 3.7

pip 20.1.1

I trid to install qiskit on Anaconda Prompt:

```
pip install qiskit
```

and it reports error while builidng wheels for cvxpy, scs, ecos:

```
Building Wheels for collected packages: cvxgy, scs
Building wheel for cvxpy(PEP 517) ... error
...
Building wheel for scs (setup.py) ... error
...
Building wheel for ecos (setup.py)... error
...
ERROR: Could not build wheels for cvxpy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

I tried to update pip and install PEP 517 after and tried again, but the error still remained.

Comment: Do you have the most up to date version of `setuptools`? Also, if you try pip installing these packages individually, do you get the same error?